# How to get values from td using DOM?

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-table

I have a table and I want to get href and td values in td that has class name ng-binding(class="ng-binding").

My current code gets the href values correctly but I want to get the corresponding td values as well(**testfolder/30 section/this-is-a-sample-video.mp4 AND testfolder/29 section/this-is-a-sample-video2.mp4**).For example i want following data:

1)https://somesite.com/sky/download/123456789/5/this-is-a-sample-video.mp4 :**testfolder/30 section/this-is-a-sample-video.mp4**

2)https://somesite.com/sky/download/123456789/5/this-is-a-sample-video2.mp4 :**testfolder/29 section/this-is-a-sample-video2.mp4**

I would appreciate if an expert show me how to get both href and values shown in bold just in front of td .Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
$html = '<table class="table no-first-border" style="margin-bottom: 0px; table-layout: fixed;">
<tbody><!-- ngRepeat: item in itemContent -->
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in itemContent">
<td class="ng-binding" style="word-wrap: break-word;">testfolder/30 section/this-is-a-sample-video.mp4
<div class="visible-xs" style="padding-top: 10px;">
<!-- ngIf: item.isViewable --><a ng-if="item.isViewable" class="btn btn-default ng-scope" ng-click="$root.openView(item);">View</a><!-- end ngIf: item.isViewable -->
<a href="https://somesite.com/sky/download/123456789/5/this-is-a-sample-video.mp4" class="btn btn-default" ng-href="https://somesite.com/sky/download/123456789/5/this-is-a-sample-video.mp4" target="_blank">Download</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="item.uploadItem()" target="_blank">Upload</a>
</div>
</td>
<!-- ngIf: hasViewables --><td class="text-right hidden-xs ng-scope" style="white-space: nowrap; width: 60px;" ng-if="hasViewables">
<!-- ngIf: item.isViewable --><a ng-if="item.isViewable" class="btn btn-default ng-scope" ng-click="$root.openView(item);">View</a><!-- end ngIf: item.isViewable -->
</td><!-- end ngIf: hasViewables -->
<td class="text-right hidden-xs" style="white-space: nowrap; width: 250px;">
<a href="https://somesite.com/sky/download/123456789/5/this-is-a-sample-video.mp4" class="btn btn-default" ng-href="https://somesite.com/sky/download/123456789/5/this-is-a-sample-video.mp4" target="_blank">Download</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="item.uploadItem()" target="_blank">Upload</a>
</td>
</tr><!-- end ngRepeat: item in itemContent -->

<tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in itemContent">
<td class="ng-binding" style="word-wrap: break-word;">testfolder/29 section/this-is-a-sample-video2.mp4
<div class="visible-xs" style="padding-top: 10px;">
<!-- ngIf: item.isViewable --><a ng-if="item.isViewable" class="btn btn-default ng-scope" ng-click="$root.openView(item);">View</a><!-- end ngIf: item.isViewable -->
<a href="https://somesite.com/sky/download/123456789/5/this-is-a-sample-video2.mp4" class="btn btn-default" ng-href="https://somesite.com/sky/download/123456789/5/this-is-a-sample-video2.mp4" target="_blank">Download</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="item.uploadItem()" target="_blank">Upload</a>
</div>
</td>
<!-- ngIf: hasViewables --><td class="text-right hidden-xs ng-scope" style="white-space: nowrap; width: 60px;" ng-if="hasViewables">
<!-- ngIf: item.isViewable --><a ng-if="item.isViewable" class="btn btn-default ng-scope" ng-click="$root.openView(item);">View</a><!-- end ngIf: item.isViewable -->
</td><!-- end ngIf: hasViewables -->
<td class="text-right hidden-xs" style="white-space: nowrap; width: 250px;">
<a href="https://somesite.com/sky/download/123456789/5/this-is-a-sample-video2.mp4" class="btn btn-default" ng-href="https://somesite.com/sky/download/123456789/5/this-is-a-sample-video2.mp4" target="_blank">Download</a>
<a class="btn btn-default" href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="item.uploadItem()" target="_blank">Upload</a>
</td>
</tr><!-- end ngRepeat: item in itemContent -->


</tbody></table>';

$counter=0;
$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
libxml_clear_errors();

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $div) {

       if($div->getattribute('class') == 'ng-binding') {
     foreach($div->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {

     $downloadurl= $link->getattribute('href');
        if ($downloadurl !="javascript:void(0);" & $downloadurl !="")
        {
          $counter++;
           echo $counter.")".$downloadurl."<br>";;        
        }
     }
     }
}

?>
```

Demo :https://eval.in/698653

Comment: Can you change the HTML so that the text you want to get is in a `<span>` or `<div>` of its own? That will make it easier to extract without all the other text in the `<td>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current `$div` element (which is actually the `<td>`) is a DOMNote, so you have the `textContent` attribute, and here you can split that string (by `\r\n` to get only the first line, which is what you are looking for).

Here is the update to your code:

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $div) {
    if($div->getattribute('class') == 'ng-binding') {
        $divContent = $div->textContent;
        $relevantContent = explode("\r\n", $divContent)[0];
        foreach($div->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
            $downloadurl = $link->getattribute('href');
            if ($downloadurl !="javascript:void(0);" & $downloadurl !="") {
                $counter++;
                echo "{$counter}){$downloadurl} :{$relevantContent}<br>\n";        
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Line breaks are just `\n` in Javascript.

Comment: it depends on the os/ide/program that saved the file. I'm currently on windows and the ide uses `\r\n` automatically (the split by `\n` will work, but it keeps the `\r` there)

Comment: and I'm not sure why it's related to javascript :)

Comment: Oops, was thinking of doing this in the client. On the server, it depends on the file's encoding. You should probably just split on `\n`, and then use `trim()` to remove any extraneous `\r`.

Comment: Many thanks for all the replies.Dekel your solution worked exactly the way i wanted :-)

Comment: If you know the content just split according to the content :)

Comment: @user1788736, you are welcome. A vote-up will also be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the text content you can use `echo $div->textContent;` but that will output

```
1)https://somesite.com/sky/download/123456789/5/this-is-a-sample-video.mp4
:testfolder/30 section/this-is-a-sample-video.mp4 View Download Upload 2)https://somesite.com/sky/download/123456789/5/this-is-a-sample-video2.mp4
:testfolder/29 section/this-is-a-sample-video2.mp4 View Download Upload
```

with the `View Download Upload` because that is text that is inside the `td` tags as well.

Comment: Isn't `DOMDocument` an HTML parser? What are you suggesting he use instead?

Answer (score 0):

To get the text you want, you need to use `$div->textContent`, but to remove the text content of sub-elements, you'll need to remove the `div` child from the `td` node:

```
foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('td') as $div) {
    if ($div->getattribute('class') == 'ng-binding') {
        foreach ($div->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
            $downloadurl = $link->getattribute('href');
            if ($downloadurl != "javascript:void(0);" && $downloadurl != "") {
                $counter++;
                $subdiv = $div->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);
                $div->removeChild($subdiv);
                $td_content = trim($div->textContent);
                echo "$counter)$downloadurl: $td_content<br>";
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Also, you have a typo in your last if: `&` should be `&&`.